# Assembly has reference to non-existent assembly 'Unity.PerformanceTesting'

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to add ECS to the project. I have added a packages: Entities, Jobs and Collections. But Unity keeps throwing me this error all the time. I have not found a solution to this problem anywhere.

Unity 2018.3.3f1

Error:

```
Assembly has reference to non-existent assembly 'Unity.PerformanceTesting'
(Packages/com.unity.entities/Unity.Entities.PerformanceTests/Unity.Entities.PerformanceTests.asmdef)
```

Edit:
I found a solution. I had to add to manifest.json

```
"com.unity.test-framework.performance": "0.1.49-preview"
```

Answer (score 9):

Maybe for other folks that come over here because of the same problem:

Help -> Reset packages to default.

This resolved the problem for me.

Comment: This will remove all the packages, it's not a solution. He needs to fix his current packages, not to clear them.